# Joomla! 2.5 use login data from another database

Tags: database, authentication, joomla

I have a hard question. I'd like the joomla login does not use its own database for users/password but I want to use my database users with my table fields, my passwords etc..

I don't know from where start, I thought I could edit database request for login to my db or create a little script to automatically add the users on joomla database.

I tried to see components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php but it seems that there is nothing.

Can someone help me figure out what to change?

Maybe the simple thing is import my database users into database user joomla, is there any plugin or something else that you know?

p.s. I use Clarion theme build on Gantry framework, Joomla! 2.5.6 Stable, PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you find or create an authentication plugin that does this for you. Joomla can support multiple authentication systems.

Have a look at creating an [Authentication Plugin for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5). The basic idea is described there.

Comment: is it ok even for joomla 2.5?

Comment: Most part of it yes. Check your Joomla! plugins which do autentication, try to understand how they are working.